# Adding a Cordova Plugin to a React App

Tags: cordova, reactjs, cordova-plugins

I am creating a mobile app in React 0.14.0 with Cordova. I am wanting to implement [this](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/calendar) calendar plugin for Cordova to be able to add some events to the users mobile calendar. I have the plugin installed and all the settings set up for the plugin, I just can't figure out how to implement the plugin into the app. When I try it has problems reading

`window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title, location, notes, startDate, endDate, this.onSuccess, this.onError);`

saying it can't read calendar of undefined. when I try to manually install the plugin, its says cordova is undefined in Calendar.js. I am very lost on how to implement a Cordova Plugin into a React, not react-native, project.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work, I was testing on a browser, which was my first mistake, and there was a typo. the plugin is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [this plugin](https://github.com/axemclion/react-native-cordova-plugin)

From the docs:

> In Cordova, all plugin methods are available on the window object. ReactNative does not run in a WebView and does not have a window object. Thus, all the methods and constants that a Cordova plugin defines are available in the Cordova object that was just required using the statement above.